# Saving multiple game files in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game for android in unity where i would like to have 3 save file. In each save file I need to be able to keep track of characters that are locked/unlocked, which levels are locked/unlocked, and the players coins and some other player info.

I have been using PlayerPrefs to save the info but i am just not sure if it is the best method since there seems to be quit a bit of info i want to save.

Is using PlayerPrefs the best method to save this info or is there a better way to save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case best choice is saving in `Application.persistentDataPath`.

To read:

```
int saveNumber = 1;
string saveFileName = "save_" + saveNumber.ToString();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (string.Format ("{0}/{1}.json", Application.persistentDataPath, saveFileName));
        string t = sr.ReadToEnd ();
        sr.Close ();
```

Just select with your logic the number of save file you are looking for. And of course parse it as you want.

EDIT:

Just to be clear, you can easly do it also with `PlayerPrefs`.

Lets say you have 3 JSON objects, and to save them with this option do something like:

```
           // To Save:
            SimpleJSON.JSONClass save_1;
            SimpleJSON.JSONClass save_2;
            SimpleJSON.JSONClass save_3;

            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("save_1", save_1.ToString ());
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("save_2", save_2.ToString ());
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("save_3", save_3.ToString ());

            // And to read:

            SimpleJSON.JSONClass save_1 = JSON.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString ("save_1")).AsObject;
            SimpleJSON.JSONClass save_2 = JSON.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString ("save_2")).AsObject;
            SimpleJSON.JSONClass save_3 = JSON.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString ("save_3")).AsObject;

            PlayerPrefs.Save();
```